# Not able to place csv data in a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a CSV file with two columns:

```
PPS_Id Amount
123    100
1234   150
```

I read data from this file and insert in a array using the code below:

```
CSV.foreach("filename.CSV", headers: true) do |row|
  file_details << row.inspect # hash
end
```

I am then trying to push the data in the `file_details` into a hash with `PPS_Id` as key and `Amount` as Value, I am using the code below:

```
file_details_hash = Hash.new

file_details.each { |x|  
  file_details_hash[x['PPS_Id']] = x['Amount']
}
```

But when I print the result I get nothing just `{"PPS_Id"=>"Amount"}`

Can you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your code, modified to work

You need to specify the column separator for your csv, and remove `inspect`.

```
require 'csv'

file_details = []
CSV.foreach("filename.CSV", headers: true, col_sep: "\s" ) do |row|
  file_details << row
end

file_details_hash = Hash.new
file_details.each { |x|
  file_details_hash[x['PPS_Id']] = x['Amount']
}

p file_details_hash
#=> {"123"=>"100", "1234"=>"150"}
```

It now returns what you expected to get.

## Shorter solution

Read the csv, drop the first line (header) and convert to a Hash :

```
p CSV.read("filename.CSV", col_sep: "\s").drop(1).to_h
#=> {"123"=>"100", "1234"=>"150"}
```

Comment: I rather ended using the below code, using your logic:

  `CSV.foreach("filename.CSV", headers: false) do |row| file_details[row[0]] = row[1] end`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are collecting strings into an array (see [`String#inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-inspect)):

```
file_details << row.inspect
```

After that you call (sic!) [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) on that strings:

```
x['PPS_Id'] #⇒ "PPS_Id", because string contains this substring
```

That said, your code has nothing but errors. You might achieve what you want with:

```
csv = CSV.parse(File.read("filename.CSV"), col_sep: "\s")
csv[1..-1].to_h
#⇒ {
#    "123" => "100",
#   "1234" => "150"
# }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `inspect` will save your CSV rows as strings, so obviously you won't be able get what you need. Instead try this:

```
file_details = CSV.read("filename.csv")
```

Read CSV directly will create an 2D array that you can then iterate over, which will look like this: `[["PPS_Id", "Amount"], ["123", "100"], ["1234", "150"]]`

From there you can slightly modify your approach:

```
file_details.each do |key, value|
  file_details_hash[key] = value
end
```

To receive a hash like this: `{"PPS_Id"=>"Amount", "123"=>"100", "1234"=>"150"}`

Comment: `Hash[*[["PPS_Id", "Amount"], ["123", "100"], ["1234", "150"]].flatten] => {"PPS_Id"=>"Amount", "123"=>"100", "1234"=>"150"}`